# Angular : binding and staying in sync with an array

Tags: angular, typescript, knockout.js, rxjs, observable

I have a service with holds a list of items. I want an angular component to display the items and stay in sync when the items change.

The list is large and I'd like the updates to be done based on change events. So I think i need something like an ObservableArray class.

But I can't find anything suitable in Angular or rxjs. Knockout has an ObservableArray, but I don't really want to bring that in just for one class.

Is there ObservableArray style class out there that I've missed or am I looking at this the wrong way (more than possible as I'm pretty new to Angular).

Thanks

Comment: Could you describe your use case in greater detail? Your question is too broad right now

Comment: The simplest thing would be to just but an array in a `BehaviorSubject` and push the updated array in when it changes, but this might not satisfy all your state management needs in the future. I think you should look into state management with angular in general. Reading about an entity store is useful even if you don't use ngrx - [Angular NgRx Entity - Complete Practical Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/ngrx-entity/). You could then also build a store with pure rxjs - [Before NgRx: Superpowers with RxJS + Facades](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-F5uYM69a4).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `combineLatest`. Lets say you have an event `removeItem$` that emits an `Observable` and a function `getItems()` that gets items from the service. You can use `combineLatest` like below

```typescript
  removeItemSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(null)
  removeItemEvent$ = this.removeItemSubject$.asObservable()
  data$ = this.myService.getItems()
  synchedData$ = combineLatest([data$, this.removeItemEvent$]).pipe(
    map(([data]) => data)
  )
```

Now with the above you can simply call `removeItemSubject$.next(null)` to reevaluate the `combineLatest` Observable which will update the data from the service.

You may also consider using the `forkJoin` operator